# Vertx test on context issues deploying verticle

Tags: java, vert.x

So this is a bit of a sneaky one, it doesn't occur 100% of the time, but this is the situation:

I created a `JUnit` integration class, declared a `Rule` to run on context, then i extract the `vertx` object from the rule. Then i deploy new verticles to the `vertx`, and if try to deploy more than ~3-4 verticles i get this for each verticle:

```
Jan 09, 2017 2:43:33 PM io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Result is already complete: succeeded
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.checkComplete(FutureImpl.java:164)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.complete(FutureImpl.java:108)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:135)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:23)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$callCompletionHandlerAsync$2(EventBusImpl.java:340)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:316)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:418)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:440)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code causing this issue looks like that:

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class VertxTest {

    @Rule
    public RunTestOnContext rule = new RunTestOnContext(Vertx::vertx);

    @Test
    public void testLinearExecution(TestContext context) {
        Vertx vertx = rule.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
            @Override
            public void start() throws Exception {
                this.vertx.eventBus().consumer("bla", event -> {});
            }
        });
        vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
            @Override
            public void start() throws Exception {
                this.vertx.eventBus().consumer("bla", event -> {});
            }
        });
        vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
            @Override
            public void start() throws Exception {
                this.vertx.eventBus().consumer("bla", event -> {});
            }
        });
        vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
            @Override
            public void start() throws Exception {
                this.vertx.eventBus().consumer("bla", event -> {});
            }
        });
        vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
            @Override
            public void start() throws Exception {
                this.vertx.eventBus().consumer("bla", event -> {});
            }
        });
        vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
            @Override
            public void start() throws Exception {
                this.vertx.eventBus().consumer("bla", event -> {});
            }
        });
    }

}
```

It might depend on the machine running it, but my guess is that if it doesn't reproduce, add more of those guys to make it more probable:

```
vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        this.vertx.eventBus().consumer("bla", event -> {});
    }
});
```

Another thing to mention is that if i change `Vertx vertx = rule.vertx();` with `Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();`, i get the warning message to console, but the problem goes away.

So, am i doing something wrong? Is it an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using version 3.3.3. You might be hitting this issue: https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/issues/1625 (fixed in master)

Comment: This has been fixed in the current release (3.4.1) and maybe earlier.